# updating IDE old to new C++ Builder

Tags: ide, upgrade, c++builder

I'm currently trying to compile an old program (made with C++ builder 2 or 3) with the "current" Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2.

So, I was wondering whether there is an easy way to use the old code, as Borland once claimed to be fully compatible to lower versions... however I couldn't find a "project-file", only source-code (.cpp, .h, .res, etc.).
I tried to "add to project" the main .cpp, however there seem to be some wrong include-paths... it also seem to use the OWL-package and includes its important source-files...

I'm a bit confused which type of main project I have to open first, since you need to open a new project before adding the source to it. As the running .exe has a GUI, I tried a Form-Window first, but it may be better to use a console or service as the real form is produced within the code as far as I understand.

So, after installing OWL and correcting the include-paths, do you think it should be running fine? Or is there something else to take care of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your old project was using OWL, you're probably well outside of the supported upgrade path. 
That being said, valid C++ code should still compile and work and I've heard of people using OWL with recent versions of C++Builder. (via [OWLNext](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/owlnext/index.php?title=Main_Page))
Regarding your confusion as to which type of project to use, I believe a console application would be your best bet. A forms application is completely wrong, that will bring in the VCL and give you no end of problems trying to reconcile the different windowing systems. A service application is a completely different beast as well, and isn't meant for GUI applications. A console application should work, but you'll need more. The [OWLNext](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/owlnext/index.php?title=Main_Page) project has a wiki that should help quite a bit.